# Can I run the run selenium web driver .net core MVC project in .net hosting server?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, asp.net-core-mvc, selenium-chromedriver

I have created the .net core MVC project for running some automated testing. Like I have created an project name TestingSelenium for the testing of another project name as Catalog.

Now, I added the code in TestingSelenium to auto open the by project URL in chrome browser and auto-login in it. This is working fine in my local pc from TestingSelenium core MVC project's by clicking to buttons. But when I update this code in the Smarterasp hosting panel and then try to click the event of that project it's not working. So I have some questions related to it.

- Is there any way to run the selenium web driver project in .net core hosting panel?
- If I want this type of functionality then is it possible? and if possible then can you inform me how?
- Basically, I want a core MVC project from that I want to open chrome browser and automation in it, please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: Running selenium in Smarterasp should work as localhost. Check the error to find the reason why not working.

Comment: It seems that you need to ask them. If you encounter error, please advise the error that you see here.

Comment: need proper answer. i am also stuck same way.

i have application that using selenium chrome driver and it is working on local.
but how to provide chrome driver path on web host ?

my application is hosted on smarter asp...